# Does the bible teach the intercession of the saints?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, eastern-orthodox, intercession-of-saints

Roman Catholics and Orthodox Christians argue that intercession of the saints is a biblical practise, but where in the bible do we find the intercession of the saints?

Comment: Revelation 6:9–11.

Comment: Hi cj564. One way to encourage people to answer questions is to accept an answer (click the check mark) to your previous questions. Each question can have 1 selected answer, if the asker believes it best answers the question.